# What is the error in the code?

Tags: c, stack

In the following function. I tried using stack and implementing using arrays. I made create stack , push , pop, functions. But on compiling it shows an error. please help me figure out what the problem is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack_struct {
    char a[100];
    int top;
};

typedef struct stack_struct *stack;

stack charc;

stack createstack() {
    stack s = (stack) malloc(sizeof(struct stack_struct));
    s->top = -1;//initialize the stack
    return s;
}

void push(stack s, char x) {
    s->top++;
    s->a[s->top] = x;
}

char pop(stack s) {
    assert(s->top > 0);
    char x;
    x = s->a[s->top];
    s->top--;
    return x;
}

void printstack(stack s) {
    while (s->top != -1) {
        printf("%c", s->a[s->top]);
        s-> top--;
    }


void main() {
    charc = createstack();      
    push(charc, 3);
    printstack(charc);
    pop(charc);
    printstack(charc);
    push(charc, 4);
    printstack(charc);
    push(charc, 5);
    printstack(charc);
    push(charc, 6);
    printstack(charc);
    push(charc, 7);
    printstack(charc);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error and the line number?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you shouldn't cast `malloc`

Comment: Hiding pointers with `typedef` is error prone, considered bad practice, makes code harder to read...

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `}` in the end of printstack function and have one extra `}` at the end of your code. Add the missing one and delete the extra one and it will compile. Also, your main function should return int (`int main()` instead of `void main()`) and you should `return 0;` from your main function

Comment: i have learnt that return 0; isn't necessary at the end. and also even after doing that (what you told me to) it is showing pop; assert function fails.

Comment: That's because your printstack function effectively empties your stack, so `s->top` is set to -1. Assert fails, because `s->top` is not greater than `0`. And even though your program will compile with `void main()`, you should not do it, the proper way is `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed problems in your code:

- There is a missing `}` at the end of the function definition for `printstack`
- Since you have an extra `}` at the end of the file, after the definition of `main()` and since `gcc` allows local function definitions, the error message is probably very difficult to interpret.
- The assertion in `pop` should read `assert(s->top >= 0);` since `s->top == 0` indicates a stack with one element present.
- The prototype for `main` should be either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalent.  Returning `0` at the end of `main()` is optional in C99 and later, but considered good style.
- Casting the return value of `malloc()` is unnecessary and can hide some problems if you omit to include `<stdlib.h>`, don't to it in C code.
- Hiding pointers behind `typedef`s is not recommended, it tends to make the code harder to read and it often leads to programming errors.  A `stack` is an object, **not** a pointer to an object. Using implicit pointers makes the difference less evident and creates confusion.
- `printstack` should not modify the `stack`, it should use a local variable:

  ```
  void printstack(const struct stack_struct *s) {
      for (int i = s->top; i >= 0; i--) {
          printf("%c", s->a[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
  ```
- Using global variables is not required for your code, make `charc` local to the `main` function and `free` it before exiting the program.
- The stack element type should be `int` instead of `char`, since you are push numbers on to the stack.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stack {
    int a[100];
    int top;
} stack;

stack *createstack(void) {
    stack *s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
    s->top = -1; // initialize the stack as empty
    return s;
}

void push(stack *s, int x) {
    s->a[++s->top] = x;
}

int pop(stack *s) {
    assert(s->top >= 0);
    return s->a[s->top--];
}

void printstack(const stack *s) {
    for (int i = s->top; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d ", s->a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    stack *st = createstack();

    push(st, 3);
    printstack(st);
    pop(st);
    printstack(st);
    push(st, 4);
    printstack(st);
    push(st, 5);
    printstack(st);
    push(st, 6);
    printstack(st);
    push(st, 7);
    printstack(st);

    free(st);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sir it is not showing the integers what should i do?   @chqrlie

Comment: @pottersher: I updated the answer with some fixes, and use `int` as the element type to make the stack contents printable.